# What does 'In and out of time' mean?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

I've encountered the phrase `I can feel your heart beat in and out of time` in the song `Call To Arms, Angels And Airwaves` and can't figure out what it means.

Does it mean that the heart beat is timeless? Or that it is constant (throughout eternity)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"In time" and "out of time" can be a musical reference, referring to a [time signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature). Especially in pop music, "time" refers to the [beat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28music%29) of the song.

For example if a musician says,

> You are playing that rhythm out of time.

It means you are not playing the correct rhythms, maybe playing in the wrong time signature or adding / dropping a beat, or playing too fast or too slow.

When you are surprised, startled or scared by something, we say your heart "[skips a beat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/heart+skips+a+beat)".

When a heart beats in time, it is beating with an even rhythm.

So to answer your question, my interpretation is that he's making a poetic phrase which includes sentiments of being startled, but safe with the support of a loved one.